# Cant Download Outlook Attachment content with Microsoft Graph Api through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I am a relatively new jr. systems administrator, so please feel free to let me know if I'm doing anything out of the ordinary with the way I'm making these API requests.
I am attempting to download some attachments from Outlook for some automated statistical analysis. I have to grab all of the attachments from a specific email that we use for statistics, which have come in each day. I am currently using the Microsoft Graph API through powershell. When I attempt to download the attachments, I see they get downloaded. However, though they are named correctly, there is nothing inside of them, sizes showing 0kb. (if it matters, the files are .xlsx and .xml files, and a total of 3 should be downloaded). I have searched through the forums for problems similar to mine, but none seem to have helped.

Thank you in advance!

I have the app set up in AzureAD, the Roles correct, and permissions set to Microsoft Graph Mail.Read, and Exchange.ManageAsApp.

For reference, here is my powershell script, with some information redacted.

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Mail
#Azure app id and secret
$clientId = "Redacted"
$clientSecret = "Redacted"
$tenantId = "Redacted"
$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"
$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    resource      = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
}
$accessToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUrl -Method Post -Body $body
$currentDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
#Url for email attachments
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@companydomain.com/messages?`$filter=receivedDateTime ge $currentDate&`$orderby=receivedDateTime desc&`$top=5"
#Grab each email attachment from url
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($accessToken.access_token)"}

# Loop through $response to download each attachment
function DownloadAttachments {
    foreach ($message in $response.value) {
    #Cycle attachments
    $messageId = $message.id
  
    Write-Host "Getting attachments for message: $messageId"

    $attachmentsUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@companydomain.com/messages/$messageId/attachments"

    $attachments = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $attachmentsUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($accessToken.access_token)"}
    
    foreach ($attachment in $attachments.value) {
        #Download attachments
        $attachmentId = $attachment.id

        $attachmentUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@companydomain.com/messages/$messageId/attachments/$attachmentId"

        $attachmentInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $attachmentUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($accessToken.access_token)"} 

        $attachmentName = $attachmentInfo.name

        Write-Host "Downloading attachment: $attachmentName"

        $attachmentContentUrl = $attachmentInfo['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl']

        $attachmentContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $attachmentContentUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($accessToken.access_token)"}

        $attachmentContent | Set-Content -Path "C:\Path\To\Downloads\$attachmentName" -Encoding Byte
        }
    }
}
DownloadAttachments
```